# Getting an error message from old code that is already deleted in Java eclipse

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I made a class where I tried to connect to a database and then insert values into a table. I made the mistake of putting a non existing table name and received the following error message.

> Fehler beim Einfuegen des Datensatzes: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

The first line is in German and says Error by insertion of dataset (record).
I decided to leave that alone so I deleted the code and class from my project. I started working on another code where I created a new class with Code that is trying to read in a CVS file but when I try to run the Code I still get the same old Error as above. I looked online but I don't see how I can fix it. I assume its something simple but I don't see what it is.

Comment: Speaking of the code: 1. Did you write two different classes each one with a main method? 2. Are both classes in the same project or are they two different projects, each one containing one of these classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clean the local cache of eclipse: click project -> clean.

Comment: Thank you what you have said worked however I received another Error Could not find or load main class DataGenerator

Comment: @user296098 If this is a maven project,  maven install again.

Comment: I assume its not a maven project. I meant to explain more. The DataGenerator was the old class that i deleted. I some how cant get rid of it.

Comment: I believe I just figured it out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

that's a database error code meaning that you are trying to insert data into a table/view that hasn't been defined. Typically it's a typo in the Java code misspelling the name of the table or the database schema needs to be updated to create the table in question.

Comment: No like I said I have written new code and a new class that has nothing to do with Database or trying to connect to a database. Im not even inserting any code to a database

Comment: Do I have to delete the whole project?

Comment: Like I said, that error is being returned by the database , have you cleaned and rebuilt your project ?